# In Ruby, is there an equivalent method of printNl as in Smalltalk?

Tags: ruby, smalltalk

If Ruby is strongly influenced by Smalltalk, I wonder if there is an equivalent method in Ruby that is similar to `printNl` in Smalltalk?

I was quite fascinated by the idea that in Smalltalk, you actually have something, like a string, and then you send the message `printNl` (for print with Newline) to the string object.  It is doing it in the OOP way, instead of the procedural way of `p obj` or `puts obj`.

I found only a `display` method for `Object`, which doesn't have a `displayNl` alternative.  Is there one in Ruby?

Just for fun I did the following, but I wonder if it may be not good if it contaminates the Object class:

```
class Object
  def displayNl
    self.display
    "\n".display
  end
end

"hello world".displayNl
5.displayNl
3.14.displayNl
Time.now.displayNl
Time.displayNl
Fixnum.displayNl
[1,3,5].displayNl
{foo: "bar"}.displayNl

-----------------

$ ruby try.rb 
hello world
5
3.14
2015-12-16 14:44:09 -0800
Time
Fixnum
[1, 3, 5]
{:foo=>"bar"}
```

Comment: Something to consider is that Ruby isn't SmallTalk. While they have similarities, trying to make one language use the other's syntax or methods results in code that isn't intuitive, especially to others who have to work on it after you wrote it. Maintenance, and being kind to co-workers, is extremely important for the viability of code. I'd recommend embracing Ruby's own way of doing things for Ruby code, and remain true to SmallTalk's way when writing code there. You'll find that as you work in more languages it becomes easier to jump back and forth. Or you'll go crazy. Like most of us.

Comment: Smalltalk isn't SmallTalk either ;)

Comment: @theTinMan actually, Ruby followed Smalltalk in making all the values objects, so it does make sense if object prints itself out, like how it was done some 50 years ago.  Of course, if Ruby didn't do it that way and everybody is following suit, wouldn't that be the way it is... but if there is a `display_nl`, then I don't see why using it has negative impact other than other people not familiar with it

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia so it is JavaScript and Smalltalk huh...

Answer (score 3):

> I wonder if it may be not good if it contaminates the `Object` class

Exactly! Why should it be the responsibility of an object to print itself to the console? Doesn't it make more sense to be the responsibility of the console to print strings?

That's exactly how it works in Ruby: [`IO#print`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-print) (and [`IO#puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-puts)) allows an [`IO`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html) object to print strings to itself, and the [`#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-to_s) protocol allows any object to represent itself as a string.

[`Kernel#print`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-print) (and [`Kernel#puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-puts), [`Kernel#p`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-p)) is simply a convenience method, which basically looks like this:

```
module Kernel
  private def print(*args)
    $>.print(*args)
  end
end
```

`$>` is the default output stream, at startup it is the same as `$stdout` and [`STDOUT`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#STDOUT), but it can be re-assigned. It is an instance of `IO`.

`IO#print`, in turn, looks like this:

```
class IO
  def print(*args)
    args.map(&:to_s).each do |str|
      some_internal_io_method_to_print_strings(str)
      # in a C-based Ruby implementation probably calling fputs from the libc
    end
  end
end
```

So, in other words, Ruby *does* it the "OO way". There are `IO` objects which know how to print strings, and there's the `#to_s` method which allows an object to represent itself as a string.

---

In other words: I consider [`Object#display`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#display) a mistake.

You might notice, that in YARV, it is actually defined in [`io.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/io.c) and not in [`object.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/object.c), so even the authors seem to agree that this functionality belongs to `IO`, not `Object`.

It is a rather old method, [the oldest trace](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blame/210367ec889f5910e270d6ea2c7ddb8a8d939e61/io.c#L1706-L1721) I could find is [this commit from January, 1999](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/210367ec889f5910e270d6ea2c7ddb8a8d939e61), which seems to be from the [version 1.3.1 release](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/210367ec889f5910e270d6ea2c7ddb8a8d939e61/version.h). Here, it is actually [defined in `Kernel`, not `Object`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blame/210367ec889f5910e270d6ea2c7ddb8a8d939e61/io.c#L2723).

Before that, the trace gets lost in the mist of the CVS2SVN conversion.

Comment: but if you say, why should a string know how to print itself, then you may say, why should a shape or circle or rectangle know how to draw itself, so `rectangle.draw` or `view.draw` all shouldn't do that and it should be `window.draw(view)` and then in `window.draw()`, you will use a `case` statement to switch between drawing a view or a textbox or a button, then polymorphism is not at work.

Comment: I'm not going to flag it (I actually upvoted), but isn't this technically "not an answer"?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such equivalent. Your example is a valid implementation, though maybe not the most idiomatic in Ruby.

Ruby methods use `snake_case` as opposed to `camelCase`. Also, it'd be simpler to just use `puts` in your method, as `puts` automatically appends a newline character.

```
class Object
  def display_nl
    puts self
  end
end
```

I've often wished for a method like this after typing a long line into IRB. Rather than moving the cursor back to the beginning of the line to add `puts` in front of everything, I'll usually just use `puts _` on the next line. A postfix method like this would be lovely.

Comment: I was using `display` just so that it has the same behavior... not sure if `puts` has everything identical to `display`... by the way, you are aware, at least on the Mac and maybe Linux, you can press Ctrl-a and the cursor will move to front of line?

Comment: I'm aware of Ctrl-a. There's more to it than just going to the front of the line. Sometimes you need to wrap the whole thing in parentheses because you've used `{}` inline block syntax, which messes up `puts`. In every case, it'd be easier to just have a method you can tack onto the end, like what you've suggested here.

Comment: yeah, isn't it true that if there is a `.display_nl`, then polymorphism can work, such as if the app want to print out something in the console and also send that string to a GUI window that shows at most 5 lines of status at the top of the graph it is plotting... or something like that, then redefine `display` and everything will work

Comment: Submit a feature request: go to https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/issues/new and register if you aren't already. Better yet, create the patch first and add it to your submission to the issue tracker. I'd support it.